# Screen size layout android

Tags: java, php, android

anyone can help? I have a coding which is nearing completion. the problem is when run in nexus 5. The applications that run lag, and the position is not appropriate. please help. need performance fix. i have html,but.... the character here not enough. curenntly i using nexus 5

sorry but i put my full code at mega

https://mega.nz/#!6sBz0ARL!9qpQKW5rr-PQ8Lpedyanyqm7NS1RM-IsQ6lOIEb989s

this is my code

css androidtab7

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-family:'MelbourneRegular',Helvetica,sans-serif,Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    background-color:#186185;
    color:#333;
}

#wrapper {
    width:1024px;
    height:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#top{
    width:1024px;
    height:490px;
    margin:0 auto ;
}


#itemlist {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left:5px;
    padding:0;
}

#itemlist.box {
    background:url("../images/bg.png") repeat scroll left top transparent;
    margin: 8px 0px 0 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 322px;
    height: 476px;
    border-radius:6px 0 0 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px 0 0 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px 0 0 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;
    box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;
}

#itemlist.box .top {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 0;
    width: 287px;
}

#containerscroll {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#scrollbox {
    border: medium none;
    margin: 5px 5px 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: auto;
}

#contentscroll {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: medium none;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.itemlist {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.itemlist table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#amount {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height:normal;
    letter-spacing:normal;
    margin: -1px 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    width: auto;
    height: 47px;
}

#amount .total {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ddd; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #060;
    letter-spacing:0.1em;
    background:#390; 
    height:43px; padding:0 5px 0 0; 
    margin:0; 
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
}




#menu{
    width:690px;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-right:5px;
    height:84px;
    background:url("../images/bg.png") repeat scroll left top transparent;  
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:0px 6px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 6px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px 6px 0px 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;
    box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;
}

#text_info{
    width:690px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-right:5px;
    height:16px;
    background:url("../images/bg.png") repeat scroll left top transparent;  
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    /*border-radius:0px 6px 6px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 6px 6px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px 6px 6px 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;
    box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;*/
}

#main_menu{
    width:690px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-right:5px;
    height:372px;
    background:url("../images/bg.png") repeat scroll left top transparent;  
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:0px 0px 6px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 0px 6px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 6px 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;
    box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;
}


#bottom{
    bottom:0;
    width:1014px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100px;
    margin:0 5px 5px ;
    position:fixed;
    background:url("../images/bg-foot.png") repeat scroll left top transparent;
    border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;
    box-shadow:inset rgba(172,204,255,0.2) 0 1px 0,#333 0 1px 5px,#333 0 1px 5px;
}



 {
text-shadow: none !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
-webkit-border-radius:0 !important;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:0 !important;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0 !important;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0 !important;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0 !important;
}
```

it's almost done

Comment: Please post your (relevant) code in your question. Don't link to a google drive - especially if it is not accessible due to missing access rights.

Comment: Please share your code along with your XML for better understanding.